# extracting middle OR final part of a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to extract only the first fontname out of a URL-string from the Google Webfont Directory. Here are some examples of possible strings and what part should be returned:

```
fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway              // "Raleway"
fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Caesar+Dressing      // "Caesar Dressing"
fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400      // "Raleway"
fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway|Fondamento   // "Raleway"
fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Caesar+Dressing|Raleway:300,400|Fondamento  // "Caesar Dressing"
```

So sometimes it's just one fontname, sometimes it has a weight indicated by a colon (`:`) and sometimes there are more fontnames divided by a pipe (`|`).

I have tried `/family=(\S*)[:|]/` but it only matches the strings with `:`or `|`. I could do it like this, but it's not a nice solution:

```
var fontUrl = "fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Caesar+Dressing|Raleway:300,400|Fondamento";
var fontName = /family=(\S*)/.exec(fontUrl)[1].replace(/\+/, " ");
if (fontName.indexOf(':') != -1){
    fontName = fontName.split(':')[0];
}
if (fontName.indexOf('|') != -1){
    fontName = fontName.split('|')[0];
}
console.log(fontName);
```

Is there a nice `regex` solution to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of matching the character that (might) follow the string you want, match only the string you want *except those characters*:

```
/family=([^\s:|]*)/
```

Alternatively, you'd use a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) like this:

```
/family=(\S*?)(?=$|[:|])/
```

Comment: could you please explain `[^\s:|]` to me?

Comment: Check out [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). Since `\S` == `[^\s]`, (`\S` without `[:|]`) == `[^\s:|]`

Comment: @AvL You could say it means any character except white spaces (`\s`), colons and pipes. `[^]` basically means 'not matching' this and that character following the caret in the square brackets.

Answer (score 1):

That should be better:

```
/family=([^:|]*)/
```

Of course for the `+` case, you'll have to replace it afterwards (or before maybe).

Comment: Thank you. I did the `+`part like this: `/family=([^:|]*)/.exec(fontName)[1].replace(/\+/, " ")`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
/family\=(\S+?)[\:\|,]{0,2}\S*/ims
```

Comment: this is not cutting the string before `:`or `|`. It's the same as `family=(\S*)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use (choose the i and m modifier in all case):

```
family=([a-z]+\+?[a-z]+)
```

or more simply

```
family=([a-z+]+)
```

or to avoid matching the + char:

```
family=([a-z]+)\+?([a-z]+)?
```

but it is an easyer way to use the second solution, and to replace the + chars with a space after.

Comment: @Jerry: You don't have read! I precised to use the i modifier. Underscores are not needed

Answer (score 0):

No regex is required in this case, unless you are good with regex's or test them thoroughly then you are likely to make mistakes.

```
var fontUrls = [];

fontUrls.push("fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway");
fontUrls.push("fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Caesar+Dressing");
fontUrls.push("fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400");
fontUrls.push("fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway|Fondamento");
fontUrls.push("fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Caesar+Dressing|Raleway:300,400|Fondamento");

function getFirstFont(url) {
    return url.split("=")[1].split("|")[0].split(":")[0];
}

fontUrls.forEach(function (fontUrl) {
  console.log(getFirstFont(fontUrl));
});
```

on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/PvTpN/)